Should I change JAVA_HOME path as same with android studio?
I get below error
Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because the Gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME locations are different. Project 'android' is using the following JDK location when running Gradle: '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home' The system environment variable JAVA_HOME is: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home' If you dont need to use different paths (or if JAVA_HOME is undefined), you can avoid spawning multiple daemons by setting JAVA_HOME and the JDK location to the same path.

So which mean should I change JAVA_HOME path to /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home?
But when I type echo $JAVA_HOME, I returns below path ..?
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home

I don't know which Java is used now between 3.
My flutter project android build keeps throwing several errors,
If I change 1 error another one comes.
I think 'java setting in my mac' seems broken.
I don't know many things about java setting.. please advise me.

Yes, right, you have to change JAVA_HOME path.
In error message, it mentioned your Android Studio is using the JDK located at:
'/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home'
Then, you have to change the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the JDK location used by Android Studio

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
